# Как решить проблему связанную с переходом по якорю?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Всем привет, есть вот такой код

```
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#navabout").on("click","a", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var id  = $(this).attr('href'),
            top = $(id).offset().top - 48;
        $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: top}, 1500);
    });
});
</script>
```

Что делает скрипт - плавный переход по якорям, также я указала значения высоты своего навбара, чтобы переход был чуть выше, чем сам якорь.

Не могу понять один баг в этом скрипте, по какой-то причине при первом переходе по якорю на странице не срабатывает вычитание, при всех дальнейших скрипт отрабатывает как надо.

Comment: добавьте в код `console.info(top)` что он выводит в **первый раз**?

Comment: Выведите в консоль значение top и величину `.offset().top`

Comment: @De.Minov выводит значение 981 первый раз и последующие 933

Comment: @Greg--, значение то 981, а offset - 1029

Comment: @АлинаСотская, проверьте на какой элемент поставлен якорь, может не тот который нужен.

Comment: @АлинаСотская попробуйте заменить ready на `$(window).load`  поменяется значения? Возможно что то недогрузилось и потом размер меняется

Comment: @De.Minov, по якорям все правильно.

Comment: @Greg--, вообще перестал работать скрипт)

Comment: @Greg--, сделала через window.load = func . Изменений 0 (

Comment: Хорошо какую то демку сделать с такой же ошибкой в виде снипетта. При подготовке демки обычно пропадают все вопросы в большинстве случаев так как при выпиливании ненужного для демки кода находится виновник торжества.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос закрыт, проблема была в том, что у меня есть скрипт, завязанный на навбаре, который после скролла задает навбару определенное положение на сайте, поэтому скрипт относительно перехода по якорям работает некорректно. Всем большое спасибо за ответы.

UPD В общем, объясню чуть более подробно ситуацию.
У меня на сайте есть шапка и навбар. Есть скрипт, который при скроле на 100px дает навбару значения position: fixed; top: 0; чтобы навбар при загрузке страницы не перекрывал шапку и из-за некоторых особенностей сайта.

Из-за того, что шапка не имеет постоянного расположения скрипт для перехода по якорю работал не совсем правильно и отсчитывал сначала значения от обычного расположения навбара, а потом уже считал от приведенных выше параметров.

То есть при нажатии на ссылку в навбаре со свойствами postion: unset, скрипт считал от одного значения top, а при нажатии на ссылку в навбаре со свойством postion: fixed, он считал уже от другого значения.

(Когда у вас случается подобная проблема, сделайте в для себя демку без лишнего кода и проанализируйте из-за чего может быть проблема)

Comment: постарайтесь дать более развернутый ответ, пожалуйста

Comment: @asianirish, так более понятен стал мой ответ? могу что-то более подробно описать